# log4j2 - configure stderr redirect/ignore for specific package

Tags: java, logging, junit, log4j2, stderr

I am using a 3rd party library in my tests.
The library prints exceptions to the stderr and they show up in the console.

What I want to do is to ignore them.

I was able to write a java-hack code to intercept the stderr

`System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
    public void write(int b) {
    }
}));`

But this will disable all of the stderr when running the junit - I want to just disable the stderr from the specific package.

I have a log4j2-test.xml for my junits, but I couldn't find any example which shows how to control the stderr at **package level**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One of the more cheaty ways to solve this problem is by providing your own implementation for the error stream. This error stream then creates an exception internally, and uses that to see where the original exception is being printed. This is certainly abuse of exceptions.

A "simple" implementation of this is:

```
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new OutputStream() {
        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            Exception e = new Exception();
            StackTraceElement[] elements = e.getStackTrace();
            boolean hasSeenPrintStackTrace = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
                if (
                    elements[i].getClassName().equals("java.lang.Throwable") &&
                    elements[i].getMethodName().equals("printStackTrace")
                ) {
                    hasSeenPrintStackTrace = true;
                } else {
                    if (hasSeenPrintStackTrace) {
                        if (
                            elements[i].getClassName().equals("me.ferrybig.testpackage.ExceptionTester") &&
                            elements[i].getMethodName().equals("log1")
                        ) {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.write(b, off, len);
        }

        @Override
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            // TODO copy above implementation to here, exceptions printing only seems to use the above method
            System.out.write(b);
        }
        public void write(int b) {
            // TODO copy above implementation to here, exceptions printing only seems to use the above method
            System.out.write(b);
        }
    }));
```

The above code basically follows all stack trace elements, till it finds the `java.lang.Throwable` class, and the `printStackTrace` method. From that point it sets a boolean flag, so it can inspect *all* frames following it, and scan if those contain a certain class and method combination. This is then used to *filter*  that write call out, so it doesn't end up in the final output.

Full demo class: http://tpcg.io/5xnlZ7